# Lock the screen

Tags: android, passwords, locking

I want to lock the application with a specific password specified by the user from the application itself.

> For example if it receives the SMS "LOCK WITH PASSWORD abc" it should
>   lock the phone with abc.

I had tried it with device administrator. But it only lock the phone.

The code I used is.....

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON); 
                filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

                ComponentName mAdminName = new ComponentName(ScreenLockService.this,LockActivity.class);

                if(!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName))
                {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                    intent1.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
                      intent1.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,"is locked");
                      intent1.putExtra("force-locked", DeviceAdminInfo.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK);

                    context.startActivity(intent1);
                    System.out.println("The Device Could not lock because device admin not enabled");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activate The DeviceAdmin and then Click start Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //mDPM.lockNow();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("The Device  device admin enabled");
                    Intent  intent1 = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                    intent1.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
                    intent1.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,"onEnabled");
                    mDPM.lockNow();
                    mDPM.setMaximumTimeToLock(mAdminName, 0);
                    intent1.putExtra("force-locked", DeviceAdminInfo.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK);
                    context.startActivity(intent1); 
}
}
```

Is there any way to make it possible..

Answer (score 1):

you have to use resetPassword

From docs

`public boolean resetPassword (String password, int flags)`

> Force a new device unlock password (the password needed to access the entire device, not for individual accounts) on the user. This takes effect immediately

then call the lock method to lock the device

`mDPM.lockNow()`